# R not working - how to fix it?

Tags: android

I want to bring some Animations `res/anim` in my App.

Sadly there is a problem to see the XML-File in my code. It looks very randomly with the auto generating of the ID in the R Class. Sometimes the XML-File get the ID int = 0 (But with a fault then in compiling...) or there is absolutly no reference. Or sometimes there are (right) References to XML-Files which are not more existing.

Have anyone an idea what I do wrong? It's my first real Project in AS, so it could be a stupid fault.

Comment: You should use the ids generated by android as references. View.getId() == R.some_element.id. R holds all generated static values.

Answer (score 0):

usually R class contains information about build and used resources. So, if you have 0 id of the element, it means:
-Project hasn't been compiled.
-You have mistake in calling id of the resource.

G_V correctly demonstrated how you should use R class. But i would like to some explain:

-Sometimes you should manually write something like:`import name_of_project.package_name.R`. 
-Some times full rebuild will help you.

Btw. could you demonstrate you error via code?

Answer (score 0):

Okay Problem solved.

Rebuild the Project was the right button... Now i have a ID and the XML File is visible in R.

Thank you!